# Select Null From A Table When Records May Not Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a largish( 10's of millions of rows)  SQL table, that lists attribute types, and attributes. I want to investigate the relationship between subsets (three or four at a time) of these attributes, for a given object. The objects may have some, all, or none, of the attributes that I'm interested in. If it has none of the attributes that I'm interested in, I can consider it not to exist.

```
Id | AttributeType | AttributeValue 
------------------------------------
01 |     01        |     100        
01 |     02        |     4500
01 |     04        |      D
01 |     15        |      E
```

The problem is, essentially that I want to return results for all the attributes types that I'm in if any of them exist, but no result if none of them do.

So performing this query:

```
select
    case 
        when Att1.id is null then Att2.id 
        else Att1.id
    end as Id, 
    Att1.AttributeValue as Attribute5, 
    Att2.AttributeValue as Attribute6
 from Attributes Att1
full outer join Attributes Att2
on Att1.id = Att2.id
and Att1.AttributeType = 5
and Att2.AttributeType = 6
```

Doesn't work for Id 1 because it has no attribute of either type, but the query create null records on either side of the join, so I see something like this:

```
Id | Attribute5 | Attribute6
-----------------------------
01 |    100     |   Null     
01 |   4500     |   Null
```

If I try to avoid creating the null records I miss out on records that I want to see. This query:

```
select
     case 
         when Att1.id is null then Att2.id 
         else Att1.id
     end as Id, 
    Att1.AttributeValue as Attribute1, 
    Att2.AttributeValue as Attribute2
from Attributes Att1
full outer join Attributes Att2
on Att1.id = Att2.id
where Att1.AttributeType = 1
and Att2.AttributeType = 3
```

produces nothing, but should produce:

```
 Id | Attribute1 | Attribute3
-----------------------------
 01 |    100     |   Null
```

I can fix both of these problems by using a left join,

```
select
    case 
        when Att1.id is null then Att2.id 
        else Att1.id
    end as Id, 
    Att1.AttributeValue as Attribute1, 
    Att2.AttributeValue as Attribute3
from Attributes Att1
left join Attributes Att2
on Att1.id = Att2.id
and Att2.AttributeType = 3
where Att1.AttributeType = 1
```

produces the correct output.

The problem with this that it doesn't treat the attributes equally. So, if Id 01 has a value for attribute 01 but not 03 it's fine, but if it didn't have 01, and did have 03, I wouldn't see it. This becomes more of a problem when I extend to three and four joins.

Ideally, given how often I'm going to have to run this query for different attribute types, and how much processing time goes into creating the attribute table in the first place, I'd love to be able to get all the results that I need, and no others, with a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
select distinct
    base.id, 
    Att1.AttributeValue as Attribute1, 
    Att2.AttributeValue as Attribute2,
    Att3.AttributeValue as Attribute3,
    Att4.AttributeValue as Attribute4
from Attributes base
left join Attributes Att1 on base.id = Att1.id and Att1.AttributeType = 1
left join Attributes Att2 on base.id = Att2.id and Att2.AttributeType = 2
left join Attributes Att3 on base.id = Att3.id and Att3.AttributeType = 3
left join Attributes Att4 on base.id = Att4.id and Att4.AttributeType = 4
where base.id = 1
```

You need a "static" table, and left join the attributes on to that...

Ideally, since you're not using anything but the ID from the base table, it would be better performing if you didn't use the entire table here, but, given the layout, this will work, if only as an example.  If you know you're looking at ID 1,3,5,7, then it would probably be better to put them in a variable/temp table, and join off that to eliminate having to join your `Attributes` table an extra time.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use SQL-Server's "Pivot" functionality ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

I think the syntax for your example would be:

```
SELECT Id, [01], [02], [04], [15], [06]
from
(SELECT Id, AttributeType, AttributeValue From Attributes) att
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AttributeValue)
    for AttributeType IN ([01], [02], [04], [15], [06])
    ) AS myPivot
```

Which would give you a column for each of the four AttributeTypes with the value in each.  Note that you have to use a grouping function, so I've used MAX().  If you have more than one record for the same Id/AttributeType combination, you will only get the row returned by MAX().  For your example I get:

```
Id  01    02      04   15   06
01  100   4500    D    E    NULL
```

With millions of rows I'm not sure how this will perform, but it should be the simplest solution I know of, and it works for a reasonable number of columns.  NULLs should work automatically.

Comment: +1 - Good idea!  Just keep in mind, this will remove duplicates should there be two of a particular AttributeType.  Which is often desirable, just be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think JiggsJedi answer is a fraction more useful for what I want to do, but this seems to solve the problem too.

Comment: No worries -- glad you got what you needed!

Answer (score 1):

Preselect your data.

```
SELECT *
FROM Attributes
WHERE AttributeType IN (...)
```

then perform the Full Outer Join on this reduced set (as a view or ina WITH clause).

You can also try to only select the id and joining it onto your existing full outer join to see which is faster

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SearchFilter TABLE (AttributeType int)
INSERT @SearchFilter VALUES (1),(5),(17),(32)

SELECT a.*
FROM Attributes a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT AttributeType FROM Attributes WHERE id = a.id
  INTERSECT
  SELECT AttributeType FROM @SearchFilter
)
```